# How to find differences in a content table SQL

Tags: sql, database, data-warehouse

I would like to find records which differ from eachother, based on different datasets in the same table, which are loaded on a different date.
So if one or more attributes(except from the key) differ from eachother from dataset x loaded on 1-1-2018 and dataset y loaded on 31-12-2018.
How do i achieve this in SQL?

The key on which the compare should be made is ZIP_CODE + House_ID

Greets,

Comment: which dbms are we talking about?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

you can get previous zipcode by LAG

```
SELECT ZipCode, HouseId,   
 LAG(ZipCode, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY LoadDate) AS ZipCodeMinus1,
 LAG(HouseId, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY LoadDate) AS HouseIdMinus11   
FROM Addresses;
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if column x had a value of 10 in 1-1-2018 and a value of 15 in 31-12-2018? How do i find that record based on ZIP_CODE + House_ID?

Comment: edited my answer. you can do computation by subquerying above SQL

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to compare sets is

```
select ... a
EXCEPT
select ... b
```

but you need another

```
select ... b
EXCEPT
select ... a
```

and this doesn't tell you which columns are different.

Or you use a `full outer join`:

```
select
   coalesce(a.ZIP_CODE, b.ZIP_CODE)
  ,coalesce(a.House_ID, b.House_ID)
  ,case when a.col1 <> b.col then 'a: || a.col1 || ' b:' || b.col1 end 
  ...
from 
 ( select ....) as a
full join
 ( select ....) as b
on a.ZIP_CODE = b.ZIP_CODE
and a.House_ID = b.House_ID
and ( a.col1 <> a.col1 or
      a.col2 <> a.col2 or
      a.col3 <> a.col3 or
      ...
    )
```

If columns are NULLable you need to add more conditions checking for *one of both columns is NULL*. Of course this comparison syntax can be automatically created using the existing metadata....